# Xml, datatable, and variables - beginner questions

Tags: c#, xml, database, variables

I have a project that has to export variables and fixed values into a xml file.
The idea is to save the work done, and load it again later.

Please be aware i just beginned to study c#, so shortened explanations will be hard to understand (i've been reading about other issues as well)

In some links i've read that such this is easy when you create datatables, but on the examples i've read they only talk about fixed values, and as far as i've seen, they required the table to be created in the form (wich is not the objective).

I've tried to place a code i've found around

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));


table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
```

It's pretty neat, but, can i visualy see the table somewhere? or it's like a console list?

Can i use variables, and will it update the matrix when the program changes the variable values?

Will the table be acessible in all the forms i create in the project? Or should i create her in a separate class and make it public?

How recommended is this process when the main objective is export / import data trough xml files?

edit: i will also have to add information about checkboxes, dropdown lists, etc, not only variables, so i'm wondering if datatables are really the best way to export/import xml.

Comment: Your objective is to represent XML based data inside a DataTable? Im sorry but it wasn't really clear from your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, no, the objective is to export information into xml format, or import, into the DataTable. DataTable is just a clean easy way i've just found to organize information, but, i didnt found anything about variables, or checkboxes status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a DataTable into XML Like this:

```
string fileName =myAppPath + @"\sample.xml";

DataTable table = new DataTable();
... //your code goes here...
table.WriteXml(fileName,  XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

And read it like this:

```
string fileName =myAppPath + @"\sample.xml";
DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
newTable.ReadXml(fileName);
```

Regarding:

*Can I use variables, and will it update the matrix when the program changes the variable values?*

As for variables I guess your mean memory. And the Your DataTable is a variable and it will hold everything in memory until your write it to the file.
If on the other hand you mean binding the values on the table to a control, well that would depend on the type of of technologies you are using.

*Will the table be accessible in all the forms I create in the project?*

Variables only exists within an scope and by scope to simplify I mean any two curly brackets "{}". In web applications(ASP.NET) for example you can use something called "session' to share data across forms and of course there are way to work this arounds in most technologies but your post does not specify it.

Comment: The answer above is in regards DataTable and XML if your list are of the same type of structure the answer is yes.

Comment: I'm getting a strange error, it says DataTable couldn't be serialized, as datatable name is not set, i find it hard to understand, since it had the values set and it was created as previously

Comment: I solved the serialized problem assigning a name to the table, for example `table.TableName = "anyname";`

Comment: Also, i did some tinkering around it, and it actually takes variables into it, and updates when you read them from the table, thank you very much @Dalorzo